# how to update sqlite3 database fields in external source

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

i need to update my sqlite database which is on the external source(URL).

Comment: Good for you. What have you tried? What's not working? Show us some code!

Comment: hi dude ...
i can update my database when it's in the resource folder
but i don't have any idea how can i update when it's in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write an API or something to interact with the sqlite database. An SQLite database is by definition [serverless](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html) – so you can't interact with it directly over a remote connection.

For example write some PHP script, to preform the actions you want, on the server that hosts the database?

Comment: you mean i can't use xcode to change a field of my database in external source?

Comment: See @Dominic's comment. You will need to add more information to question to get a helpful answer. It's hard to understand your problem.

If you're editing the sqlite db in your resource folder of xcode and want it on the internet, just copy and upload it to the internet. If you want to edit an sqlite db on the internet, download it (which copying it), put in your resources folder edit it, then reupload it... 

i'm just guessing now...